# ADT shows error in Strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, resources, adt

I updated my ADT to the latest version after Gingerbread was released. And now

```
<string name="date_format">%d:%d %s</string>
```

shows the following error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" 
 attribute?
- error: Unexpected end tag string
```

Previous ADT version worked fine. Am I doing something wrong? I get this error whenever there are more than 1 format specifiers.

Comment: In my case, I wrongly entered the formatting param as 1%$s, instead of %1$s.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try doing the following

```
<string name="date_format" formatted="false">%d:%d %s</string>
```

The detailed explanation can be found in the answer to this question: [Android XML Percent Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol)

Comment: I know this thread is dead, but thanks a lot.  For whatever reason a lot of the SDK demos/examples have this problem.

Comment: This looks like a work-around, so I think hopia's answer is to be preferred - that one looks like cooperating properly with the Android Asset Packaging Tool.

Answer (score 46):

Or, alternatively, you can modify your % format specifiers to use argument indices, like so:

```
<string name="date_format">%1$d:%2$d %3$s</string>
```

More info on the Formatter class in the [Android Reference Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: I feel this is a better answer than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing this error cause of a typo:`%$3s`. Should be `%3$s`.

Just for somebody who is stupid like me:)