# Escape multiple “%” characters in Android

Tags: android, xml, escaping, arrays

In <string-array name="versions"> I have this beast of an entry (boiled down to a reasonable minimum to reproduce the effect):

```
<item>100% foo 40%bar</item>
```

which produces these errors:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
- error: Found tag </item> where </string-array> is expected
```

Adding formatted="false" doesn't change a thing.

```
<item>100&#37; foo 40&#37;bar</item>
```

results in the same error messages. WTH?

```
<item>100% foo 40bar</item>
<item>100 foo 40%bar</item>
<item>100% foo 40%</item>
```

would all work fine.
Escaping it with \% is just ignored resulting in the same error. %% doesn't result in an error but I get %%.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol/4417333#4417333 , most of that you say won't work, but see the last option.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Unfortunately I am not dealing with a string that might allow substitution at all unless there is a way to do substitutions in arrays.
In my arrays.xml there is a string-array with items. These I load via getResources().getStringArray(R.array.versions);

Comment: ouch, getStringArray uses the formatter and yet doesn't allow you to pass format arguments.  I'm afraid that you'll have to recreate the array after you load it, substiting in the %, or else correct the strings as you use them.

Comment: Java strings are immutable.  The methods return copies.

Comment: :/ urgs. Me stupid. Sorry. Much stress right now.

Comment: Yes, this last question about replaceAll was not necessary but I don't like the solution for the first one. I would say that's a bug.
Thanx Julian.

Comment: can you resort to some variation of the percent sign in the first place ? e.g. try \u066a ([arabic percent sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/66A/index.htm)).

Comment: haha collapsar :) I like your idea but I settled with %% and subsequent string replacement.
So I can't pick your solution for others that run into the same issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Encoding each as a unicode character in the xml works for me:

```
<string name="test">100\u0025 foo 40\u0025bar</string>
```

Comment: Ok, I guess this should be the way to go. Still I would like to understand why both &#37; and \u0025 are % but version 1 makes me run into the error??

Comment: I lost one good 20 minutes on this, so I hope can save time for someone else. Having String to format, I had to use e.g., Score: <b>%.2f%%</b>. Two % character, attached to the format. None of the above worked in this case.

Comment: I would not recommand replacing  % with unicode character. They are encoded but not escaped.  If you have parameter within your sentence like <string name="test">Value in percent :  %1$d  \u0025</string> and call   " int testValue = 29;
        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.test, testValue);" your application will only crash... Instead use %% (or eventually   <string name="test">Value %1$d \u0025\u0025</string> would work but really dirty)

Answer (score 48):

The `%` is a reserved character in XML like `<`, `>`, etc. 
Use `%%` for each `%` you are using in the string resource.

Comment: You are slightly late with your reply but thanks anyway :D I might test your solution if I come accross Android development soon but given I had tried `&#37;` I though I had done enough of escaping back then. `\%%` is definitely nicer than `\u0025` … well … maybe not "definitely". :)

Comment: `%%` was the only one that work for me. This is my final string
   `(%1$s%% commission)` that translates, for example, in `(2.56% commission)`

Comment: % most certainly is not a reserved character in XML; this content restriction is specific to Android resource files.

Comment: Thanks, save my hours

Answer (score 1):

Using [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) may work..

```
<item><![CDATA[100% foo 40%]]></item>
```