# Android aapt.exe APPCRASH on build project with error code -1073741819

Tags: android, intellij-idea, aapt, crash

Problem similar with this one [AAPT failing with error code -1073741819](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699439/aapt-filing-with-error-code-1073741819/14420585#14420585)

Appt.exe stops with APPCRASH on project build with signature:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: aapt.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4e810830
  Fault Module Name:    msvcrt.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bda6f
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000d193
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Messages window in IDE shows android-apt-compiler: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe package -m --auto-add-overlay --extra-packages %used libraries%" execution failed with exit code -1073741819

I tried to rebuild, clean project, clean IDE cache, add/remove dependencies, restart IDE, reboot computer, reinstall Android SDK platform-tools - nothing helps.
Solution provided in related issue also didn't help - I have no @+id in my style.xml.

IDE: Intellij IDEA 12.0.2

Libraries used in project:

- ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0
- SlidingMenu
- Android-ViewPagerIndicator
- Android-PullToRefresh

As I discovered in Eclipse this problem could be solved by setting Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build -> Build Output to "Normal" instead of "Verbose". But I cannot find such option in Intellij IDEA.

PS: looks like problem somewhere in the project because other projects (even with libraries) compiles well.

Comment: Please report it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with the sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Actually I was able to solve this issue by manually move changes (not source files, just a code and layout.xml's) to old backup of my project on other computer. I did it carefully and try to build project after each change. All were compiled and run fine. After that I move the entire project (with libs) to my main computer, clear the entire workspace, remove all projects from it and import working project from second computer. After this procedure project was comiled without problems. But I still don't know what caused that problem so I don't know what to post as sample project to reproduce.

Comment: The only idea is that something happened with project files itself. Last thing I remember before that problem occurs I did "Optimize imports" for all files in the project. While I was trying to fix the problem I moved project with libs to Eclipse but event there the project compile failed with the same error. I removed libs and add new clean libs downloaded from source sites but I still got the same error on project build even in Eclipse. Problem disappeared only after manually code re-write.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you were missing some entries in strings.xml

in my case I was deleting `<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>`

thinking it was not used by the project and placing it back solved the issue. You can search for same or similar type of tag in you project.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue.  I was cleaning up my drawable folder and deleted the wrong icon by accident.  I had to restore the file via Git to fix the issue.