# no resource found that matches the given name Android 1.6

Tags: android, resources

I've got `'no resource found that matches the given name'` but everything is set up correctly.
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name `(at 'text' with value '@string/labReminderClear')`.

---

In **AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<application android:label="MyName"
.....
```

---

In **Strings.xml:**

```
<string name="app_name">MyName</string>
...
<string name="labReminderClear">Clear</string>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Show your code - telling us there's an error without showing code which causes it doesn't help anyone solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you've mentiond contains errors in `strings.xml` file. It is connected with `%` sign used for example in following line (NOTE: there are multiple in that file):

```
<string name="msgYouHaveASTS">You have %d appointment(s)\n..and %d task(s)</string>
```

This is due to `aapt` (Android Asset Packaging Tool) becoming strict and being used for **all** versions of Android. See detailed explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4417333/480199).

If you want to fix the code so that it works correctly, you have to add info about parameters positions. For example line from above should become:

```
<string name="msgYouHaveASTS">You have %1$d appointment(s)\n..and %2$d task(s)</string>
```

Comment: Sure thing! Could you provide more links about aapt (parameter positions)?

Comment: @xaero212 Thanks. Info about parameter's position in string (used by formatters) can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) (take a look at *"Formatting strings"* subparagraph). As of AAPT itself I don't think you'll need to use it directly. Read about [build proccess](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html#detailed-build) to get info about where AAPT is used.

Comment: Thank you again. Możesz dac jakiś kontakt do siebie? ;)

Comment: Could you provide any contact info?

Comment: @xaero212 Sorry, but I'd rather not. I want my SO profile to stay disconnected from other activities (at least for now).

Comment: Ok cool. The important thing is you help a lot ;) I wanted your contact info to ask for any beginngers' tutorials to write an app such like AnCal (reminders + tasks with database sync).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using *Eclipse* try using (from menus above):

1. `Project->Clean...`.
2. Select project, in which you have problem, to be rebuilt.

If that doesn't help `Error Log` view might help you nail what is the real issue here. From Eclipse menus choose:

`Window->Show view->ErrorLog`

Comment: Is there something in `ErrorLog` view?

Comment: for example this: Plug-in "org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.ui.tasklist.BugzillaConnectorUi".

Comment: Also it would be useful to see how you want to use the string. For example in your excerpt from `AndroidManifest.xml` no defined string value is used. Instead string is directly put as value, it should be `android:label="@string/app_name"`. Are you trying to use the string value in XML or in code?

Comment: Does that mean I'm missing some plugins?

Comment: it's generally this app from here: http://code.google.com/p/ancal/source/browse/. It's open source.

Comment: @xaero212 this doesn't seem to be related. Anything else? Try building project once again with this panel opened. Also, as I've mentioned in another comment, please **include how you want to use the string value** of `@string/labReminderClear`

Comment: @xaero212 What is the exact position of that error in this open source project?

Comment: <Button android:id="@+id/btnAlarmReminderClear" android:text="@string/labReminderClear"

Comment: and the error is: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/labReminderClear'). But there is the resource defined in strings.xml.

Comment: @xaero212 See my other answer - should help :)

Comment: @xaero212 Did my other answer helped you?

Comment: I will check this later today or tomorrow, don't have access to my Eclipse now. Many many thanks for your help man!