# No resource found that matches the given name in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm getting this error when trying to build the application. The xml editor did not highlight both error as missing. As the file/string are already there.

> **android-apt-compiler**: [XXX]
>   D:\private\xxx\android\XXX\src\AndroidManifest.xml:35: error: Error:
>   No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value
>   '@drawable/ic_launcher').
>   **android-apt-compiler**: [XXX]
>   D:\private\xxx\android\XXX\src\AndroidManifest.xml:233: error: Error:
>   No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value
>   '@string/FacebookAppID').

The project structure is like this:

```
ProjectFolder
|-external_lib
|-src
    |-src (actual source)
    |-res
    |-...
```

[image: Error]

I can confirm that both file is already in the project. As I use IntelliJ, I could just Ctrl + click then it open those files for me. However, I'm still getting this error.

I checked with both Google and SO. Most of the issues were about not having the files or storing in different folders. Which I can ensure that it is in the right place alongside hundred other files and strings.

Another issue is about [% sign in strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391146/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-android-1-6). I tried searching for "%" and nothing is found in the file.

Shutting down IDE and reopen it doesn't help, nor rebuilding the project. How could I get the app to build?

Comment: Did you find a workaround on this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No, unfortunately. I ended up delete IntelliJ then reinstall everything from scratch. The issue disappear then.

Answer (score 0):

Look for any error message during the resource compilation.

Sometimes, if you have resource filenames containing illegal characters (such as underscores or uppercase letters), the whole process fails almost silently, and the IDE can't find any resources anymore.

I'm not sure that it's what is happening in your case, but I did eventually encounter such  issues...