# issue in string array in xml file: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format and Found tag </item> where </string-array> is expected

Tags: android, android-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android XML Percent Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol)

hi mate i have an array in file xml:

```
<string-array name="type_data_graph">
        <item>Veichle speed (Km/h)</item>
        <item>Engine Rpm (rpm)</item>
        <item>Barometric pressure (kPa absolute)</item>
        <item>Fuel pressure (kPa)</item>
        <item>Fuel Rail pressure of manifold vacuum (kPa)</item>
        <item>Fuel Rail pressure diesel/gasoline (kPa)</item>
        <item>MAF air flow rate (grams/sec)</item>
        <item>Intake MAP (kPa)</item>
         <item>Engine % torque (%) </item>       
......
    </string-array>
```

when commpile i get error on

```
     <item>Engine % torque (%) </item>
```

the error is

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type error: Multiple substitutions
>   specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the
>   formatted="false"
>   attribute?    arrays.xml  /DashboardDroid/res/values  line 43 Android AAPT
>   Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type error: Found tag  where
>    is expected   arrays.xml  /DashboardDroid/res/values  line
>   43    Android AAPT Problem
>   what means ??? i close all tag

Comment: The `%` is a reserved character in XML like `<`, `>`, etc. Please read this question: [Android XML Percent Symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol) (Basically use `\%%` for each `%`.)

Comment: This error appears also when you use %s or %d more than once (as attempted to describe by the error message :)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

instead of

```
 Engine % torque (%)
```

try using

```
Engine %% torque (%%)
```

if you need a % in your strings.xml file

or try checking the link [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

or else simply try giving

```
 formatted="false"
```

in your

```
<string-array>
```

tag

Comment: i use         <item>Drivers demand engine %% Torque (%%)</item>
and the error disappear but when i load by code the string i load the string "Drivers demand engine %% Torque (%%)" but i want "Drivers demand engine % Torque (%)".. how can solve it?

Comment: with  formatted="false"  work all :)

Comment: What if you do want a formatted string?

Comment: Its showing %% in my app.