# ADT shows an error in Strings.xml,how to rectify that particular error?

Tags: android, eclipse

```
<string name="content2">//C Program for Arithmetic Operations\n#include&lt;stdio.h&gt;\nvoid main()\n\tint a=10,b=12;\n\tprintf(\&quot;Addition:%d\&quot;,a+b);\n\tprintf(\&quot;Subtraction:%d\&quot;,a-b);\n\tprintf(\&quot;Multiplication:%d\&quot;,a*b);</string>
```

Shows the following error

Multiple annotations found at this line:
- error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" 
 attribute?
- error: Unexpected end tag string

Answer (score 1):

As specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605684/issue-in-string-array-in-xml-file-multiple-substitutions-specified-in-non-posit), you need to change your substitution strings from `%d` to `%%d` in order to escape the percent symbol correctly.