# finding problems in Gradle building

Tags: java, android, string, android-resources

The error is :

*C:\Users\محمود\Desktop\Pre_yea\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml
Error:(2) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
Error:(2) Found tag  where  is expected*

When I checked the strings.xml file and I didn’t find and tag that does not match the right status , Also in Java file they gave me error "cannot resolve R"

Comment: [issue in string array in xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605684/issue-in-string-array-in-xml-file-multiple-substitutions-specified-in-non-posit) Your question is similar to this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you added formatted=false then format specifiers(%,$ etc.) in your string resource is disabled and Formatter wont recognize them. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol) will definitely help you