# Write % in strings.xml of android

Tags: android

I want to create the following string array in my `strings.xml` file:

```
<string-array name="an_array_columns">
         <item>% Select percentage1</item>
         <item>% Select percentage2</item>
</string-array>
```

here the string is "% select percentage". Now, when I am writing this in my strings.xml, I am getting the following error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to 
     add the formatted="false" attribute?
    - error: Found tag </item> where </string-array> is expected
```

I know we can change `&` to `&amp;` or `'` to `\'`, but what do I do for percentage sign?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use its code. Try this: `&#37;`

Also check the similar question: [Android XML Percent Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol)

Comment: Thanks for link that is actually needed.

Comment: Did not work : `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %e can't format java.lang.Integer arguments`

Comment: got the same problem as woprandi. trying to add a percent at the end of a string formatted to allow integers. works without this added, but when I add the code above, the issue occurs.

Answer (score 112):

`%%` seems to be all that works for me. For example:

`<string name="num_percent">%1$d %%</string>`

with

`String oneHundredPercentString = getString(R.string.num_percent, 100); // This gives "100 %"`

Comment: Worked for me in `<string name="rulestats">%1$d per %2$s (1 per %3$s days) Accuracy=%4$s%%</string>` with `currentrule.setText(ctxt.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.rulestats,
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(
                            DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_USES_COL)),
                    RulePeriodAsString(ruleperiodasint,rulemultiplierasint),
                    df.format(rulequantityperday),
                    df.format(ruleaccuracy)));`

Comment: In fact this one works, but `&#37;` doesn't in case if people use string format

Comment: Thanks so much,it worked for me,&#37; deosn't work in follow way:

<string name="num_percent">%1$d &#37;</string>
getString(R.string.num_percent,10),this will crash.

Comment: this should be the excepted answer since it will work for all cases unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: It works fine in all cases, even with string format, where, unfortunately, the accepted answer doesn't work. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: That is the correct solution. It worked for me using getString with substitution. %1$s%%.

Answer (score 0):

If we want % symbol in string then try

```
<string name="_150_chance_for_a_beautiful_sky">150\% chance for a beautiful sky.</string>
binding.percentageCheck.setText(getResources().getString(R.string._150_chance_for_a_beautiful_sky));
```

If we want to format data then try

```
    <string name="test_percent">First : %d, Second : %s, third :%f, Second : %c  </string>

    String multiPercent = getResources().getString(R.string.test_percent, 150 , "Test", 2f, 'c');
    binding.multiPercentageCheck.setText(multiPercent);
```

Output

[image]