# String format in string.xml in Android layout

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout, textview

I have a string defined in my String.xml file that uses format arguments, i.e.:

```
<string name="myStr">Part No.(Part Sr. No.)</string>
```

I have assign string for TextView

```
<TextView android:text="@string/myStr"/>
```

There is error occurred for assign string value for TextView. How is it do format string for TextView?? Please help me.

Thanks!
Nitin

Comment: have you tried clean the project and found the same issue?

Comment: Typically, when one posts "I'm trying to do something but I'm given some error instead", they must post the actual error before anyone can help them.

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: First change String.xml to string.xml :-p ...
2nd What is the error ??

Comment: XML formatted error for string.xml

Comment: Check out [Android XML All Characters Allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow for all characters in your string, you must mark is as not formatted:

```
<string name="myStr" formatted="false">Part No.(Part Sr. No.)</string>
```