# Android: string format with Double value in Strings.xml

Tags: android

I need to create a String using the Formater to display some double values in application. I'm not clear on how to code it. Here is what I have:

```
<string name="diseaseMessage">You have %s message, Unread %s</string>
```

i get this error:

```
error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?  
error: Unexpected end tag string    strings.xml /TSMS Pro/res/values    line 70 Android AAPT Problem
```

Comment: Check link below:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<string name="diseaseMessage">You have %1$s message, Unread %2$s</string>
```

From the [Android docs:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

**Formatting strings**

If you need to format your strings using [String.format(String, Object...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)), then you can do so by putting your format arguments in the string resource. For example, with the following resource:

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

In this example, the format string has two arguments: %1$s is a string and %2$d is a decimal number. You can format the string with arguments from your application like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
```