# Generate a string resource containing % from build.gradle with resValue

Tags: android, xml, escaping, android-gradle-plugin

I have a custom task in my **build.gradle** which generates some string resources:

```groovy
android.defaultConfig.resValue "string", "my_string", "Some Value"
```

This all works fine: the strings appear correctly in **generated.xml** and are accessible via `getResources().getString(R.id.my_string)` in the application code.

It doesn't work when one of the strings contains a `%` symbol. It gives this error:

> Error:(1) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?

I understand from [Android XML Percent Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol) that one would normally work around this, for a string resource in **strings.xml**, by supplying the extra `formatted="false"` attribute as follows:

```
<string formatted="false">My string with a % symbol</string>
```

How can I include the `formatted="false"` attribute when the string is generated using `resValue` in the build script?

(I have also tried escaping with double-% as suggested, but that results in `%%` appearing in the final string.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by replacing the raw `%` symbol with a double-escaped unicode value at string generation time in the gradle task.

```groovy
android.defaultConfig.resValue "string", "my_string", \
    "String with a % symbol".replaceAll("%","\\\\u0025")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use % in xml

try this format \%% in your xml

```
<string name="foo">percent symbol 50\%% </string>
```