# String cannot contain two '%'

Tags: java, android, xml, string

This is all happening in my `Project -> res -> values -> strings.xml` file.

My string is as follows:

```
<string name="Bellowy">"During its action, if HP is less than 50%, increase all your creatures ATK by 30% during their next basic ATK"</string>
```

The console outputs this error `strings.xml:98: error: Unexpected end tag string`. I've identified that having two `%` signs does not register correctly in the R.java file. How can I fix this error and have two `%` signs in my `Strings.xml`?

Comment: Try `%%` instead of `%`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414389/android-xml-percent-symbol

Comment: Try using the unicode `&#37;` instead of %.

Comment: Thanks! Oddly enough, 1 `%` compiles fine, but using 2 of them in a string causes errors :O

Answer (score 2):

It must be creating some trouble due to [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) '%' is an escape character. You can use %%

Answer (score 1):

As i used you can eliminate this problem by two ways

Add formatted attribute

```
<string name="Bellowy" formatted="false">"During its action, if HP is less than 50%, increase all your creatures ATK by 30% during their next basic ATK"</string>
```

Add %% instead of %

```
<string name="Bellowy">"During its action, if HP is less than 50%%, increase all your creatures ATK by 30%% during their next basic ATK"</string>
```