# .aar Bindings library with resources fails at build time in application

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to build a binding library for the [Android Zoom SDK](https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-android/).

The SDK is contains 2 .arr files, so I ended up with 2 binding library.

When I try to use these 2 binding libraries in a demo application, I have the following error during build with resources that comes from one of them.

> multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?

I understand the problem perfectly, but can I do something about it?
It seems to me that [Transforms are all about code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/), and not about resources at all.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT 1**:

Here's my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/omatrot/Xamarin.Android.ZoomBindings) for you to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Have you looked at the comment in the answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48347534/11104068

Comment: @Saamer I saw it but the problem here is that I do not have access to resources because they're embedded in the .aar files.

Comment: Can you share some screenshots and tell me what you have tried to do so far. Can you also share a more detailed Application output, possibly inside a pastebin

Comment: @Saamer I've pushed my early work to [GitHub](https://github.com/omatrot/Xamarin.Android.ZoomBindings)

Comment: Hmm that’s a strange error. Here’s a video shared by Jonathan Dick https://youtu.be/NyqxScrnJKw where he creates bindings that could help you, specifically at 1:24:25. The XamarinComponents gitter channel is another good place to ask them for help in case you aren’t able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by the following string resources are defined in wrong format which has two $s.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Rh3.jpg)
 %s added a channel description: %s
    %s added a chat description: %s 
  %s updated the channel description: %s
   %s updated the chat description: %s

I was able to fix the issue by modifying the valuse.xml and values-{language}.xml files in the aar files (unzip it and rezip it).

BTW, I has read your posts about this topic.Cool article! Just FYI, based on my tests, we don't need to add the values.xml file into the demo project once we fix the issue.

Comment: The string were removed. Please check the screenshot.

Comment: Did you fork the GitHub repo ? You can make a pull request if you want.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Github.  I will have a try when I have some time tomorrow.

Comment: You can send me your modified project as a zip file as well. Or put it somewhere for me to download.

Comment: Here is the git hub link https://github.com/Liminghao0922/Xamarin.Android.ZoomBindings

BTW, I also fixed some other errors. 
Change the target API Level 29.
Add some Androidx Libs.

Comment: I had to add some missing colors but, it solved the problem. Now would be a good time to tell the zoom team about those strings.